# php foreach array id value

Tags: php, foreach

i have array:

`array(
id1: title_of_id_1,
id2: title_of_id_2,
id3: title_of_id_2,
)`

How to foreach get array only list `id1, id2, id3`?

Comment: Where is `$list_duan` variable?

Comment: your question is unclear please explain it well show we can answer or suggest you

Comment: @ShivCK  $list_duan is: list autocomplete i have select value, i have value select `id1: title_id1, id2: title_id2` but i don't get only id in foreach array

Comment: @DinhCode could you please show some sample values of `title_id1` ? Depending upon your values you can fetch id from value either by removing title by str_replace() or explode() or using RegEx

Comment: @ShivCK exactly value when i have echo list select:

`56: Lorem ipsum dolor, 120: Nostra class porttitor cum, 140: Ac risus vel torquent inceptos`. Value `56, 120, 140` is ID of post, i want get `array(56, 120, 140)`? can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provided proper source code of your array. So
*I couldn't understand properly I think, still I'm trying to answer.*

**If your ID number and text both are stored in `$list` array values, like this -**

> $list = array(
> 'id1:text 1',
> 'id2:text 2',
> ...
> );

then you could do something like this

```
$idArr= array();

foreach ($list as $li) {
    $id = explode(":", $li)[0]; //first value before : sign
    //$id = trim($id); //to remove spaces if any (optional)
    array_push($idArr, $id);
}


print_r($idArr); //all your ids
```

**If your array is like this**

> $list = array(
> id1 => 'text 1',
> id2 => 'text 2',
> ...
> );

Then you can do like this

```
$idArr = array_keys($list);

print_r($idArr); // your ids
```